# Retrive data from partition table using select

Tags: sql-server

I created partitions on one table. I have created the partitions using column year.

I want to retrieve the data from partition table using clause.
How can I write my select clause?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this...

```
-- fetch all the rows on the 2012 partition
SELECT
    t.name,
    t.year
FROM 
    mytable AS t
WHERE
    $PARTITION.<partition_function_name>(t.year) = $PARTITION.<partition_function_name>(2012)
```

For more info look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188071.aspx).